# Dynamic schema selection in eclipselink

Tags: jpa, annotations, eclipselink, database-schema

I am using eclipselink with Oracle in my project.

I am using annotation based mapping as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ASSIGNMENT", schema="service")
public class Assignment implements Serializable {
...
}
```

I have different schemas corresponding to different countries. The table names are the same. The requirement is to select schema names during run time.

Is it possible to achieve this using annotation based approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EclipseLink also allows the schema to be set using the tableQualifier,

see, [JPA - EclipseLink - How to configure Database Schema name at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533645/jpa-eclipselink-how-to-configure-database-schema-name-at-runtime)

Note that createEntityManagerFactory() will return the same factory for the same persistence unit name, unless you pass a property that differs (such as url, user, or ""eclipselink.session-name").

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your schemas have not only the same table names, but the same table structure too.

The way your application is designed is not good. Let's say that you have the ASSIGNMENT table in the schemas "france" and "spain". This is clearly a bad design decision as it would be much better to have a column describing the country. So it is not surprising that JPA is not quite designed for this feature.

Besides that, you still can handle this situation with JPA. You will need to look to the `EntityManagerFactory`. If you are using JavaSE specifically search for this method in the `javax.persistence.Persistence` class:

```
public static EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties);
```

And for this method in the `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory` interface:

```
public EntityManager createEntityManager(Map properties);
```

The trick is in the Map. Copying and adapting some code from [this page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/OutsideContainer), you would do something like this:

```
import static org.eclipse.persistence.config.PersistenceUnitProperties.*;
...

public final class Connector {
    private static final Map<Country, EntityManagerFactory> factoriesByCountry =
        new HashMap<>();

    private Connector() {}

    public static synchronized EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(Country country) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = factoriesByCountry.get(country);
        if (emf == null) {
            emf = createEntityManagerFactory(country);
            factoriesByCountry.put(country, emf);
        }
        return emf;
    }

    private static EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(Country country) {
        Map<Object, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

        // Ensure RESOURCE_LOCAL transactions is used.
        properties.put(TRANSACTION_TYPE,
            PersistenceUnitTransactionType.RESOURCE_LOCAL.name());

        // Configure the internal EclipseLink connection pool.
        // TODO: Personalize your connection and schema accordingly to the given Country.
        properties.put(JDBC_DRIVER, "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        properties.put(JDBC_URL,
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + country.getHost() + ":1521:" + country.getSchema());
        properties.put(JDBC_USER, country.getUser());
        properties.put(JDBC_PASSWORD, country.getPassword());

        // Configure logging. FINE ensures all SQL is shown
        properties.put(LOGGING_LEVEL, "FINE");
        properties.put(LOGGING_TIMESTAMP, "false");
        properties.put(LOGGING_THREAD, "false");
        properties.put(LOGGING_SESSION, "false");

        // Ensure that no server-platform is configured
        properties.put(TARGET_SERVER, TargetServer.None);

        // Now the EntityManagerFactory can be instantiated:
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(country.getUnitName(), properties);
    }
}
```

If you are using JavaEE, then it will strongly depend on your container, but you will need to do something similar to the above.

And obviously, after creating the `EntityManagerFactory`, you will need to get the `EntityManager`, possibly passing some others properties there. Further, you will need to track the correct `Country` everywhere. You can even connect to multiple databases by using multiple `EntityManagerFactories`, though it might be tricky to not mix and confuse managed entities from different countries, so I suggest you to add this information to every entity class to help you.

If your table structure is different between countries, then your entity classes will need to figure out that. In this case, a possible solution is to define that `Assignment` is the superclass of both `FranceAssignment` and `SpainAssignment` and you get the correct subclass accordingly to the country.