# java ee7 GF4 change schema properties at runtime

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-4, wildfly-8

I'm working with java ee7 and glassfish 4 or wildfly 8.0.1.

In an application I need to change database at runtime.

For example I need to switch from mydb2014 to mydb2015 based on user choice.

Number, name of database, access credentials, host and rdbms will be dynamic, so it's not possible to instantiate at deploy all possible persistence units.

Is there any way to achieve this goal taking advantage of CMT?

Comment: Can refer here to configure properties at runtime - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9340364/366964

Comment: I don't think that solution meets the requirement of CMT. 
Or, more likely , it's me that I can not.